# How to load data faster into RStudio from MariaDB (Example Given)?

Tags: r, mariadb, rstudio, rmysql

I am loading a dataset called df and it is 10 GB file , and it (dbGetQuery) is taking 6-8 minutes . Any suggestions to expedite this data loading script ?

```
conn <- dbConnect(MySQL(),
              host = DB$host,
              port = DB$port,
              user = DB$user,
              password = DB$password,
              dbname = "device_onboard")


df<-dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from device_onboard.onboard")
```

Comment: I mean I don't think you can speed up this SQL query in R, it is already pretty simple and efficient. You could try to ``SELECT`` the cols or the rows you really need but if you need the entire file I think you'll simply have to wait 6-8 mins each time.

Comment: Let us know when you manage to break the spead limit called "the speed of light".